# Nested loop in php works differently than expectd

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve MySQL data on a loop. But only first one is showing data. Others are empty. This is how it is working now-

[LINK](http://s15.postimg.org/laamdkjhn/Untitled.png)

Here's my code:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= $quantity; $i++) {
    echo'
        <tr>
            <!-- <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td> -->                         
            <td><input type="text" data-type="productCode" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter IMEI number"></td>
            <td><select name="brand[]"  class="form-control autocomplete_txt">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_brand)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['brand'] . '">' . $row['brand'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo'  </select> </td> <td><select name="model[]"  class="form-control autocomplete_txt" >';
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_model) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while ($row_model = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_model)) {
            echo ' <option value="' . $row_model['model'] . '">' . $row_model['model'] . '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo'   
        </select>                       
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="brand[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Brand"></td> 
        <td><input type="text" data-type="productName" name="model[]" id="itemName_2" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Model"></td> 
        <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
        <td><input type="number" value="1" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" disabled></td>
        <!-- <td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" disabled></td> -->                             
    </tr>
    ';
}
?>
```

I'm not sure what is the problem actually.

Comment: Please show us the query for brand and model

Comment: @Kuya: Just added the query.

Comment: Did you check the output of `mysqli_num_rows($result_model)`? See if it is indeed > 0?

Comment: @minitauros: it has 24 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the cursors of your `mysqli` results are pointing at the end of result after the `while` loop has run once.

You have to call [mysqli_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.data-seek.php) at the beginning of your `for` loop to reset the cursors to the first dataset:

```
for($i=1; $i<=$quantity; $i++) {
    mysqli_data_seek($result_brand, 0);
    mysqli_data_seek($result_model, 0);
...
```

Another solution is to run the `while` loops once before your `for` loop and store the results in arrays so that you are using your arrays instead of using `mysqli_fetch_array` inside your `for` loop.

Comment: @mario.klumo: you are my hero